# Heat causing concrete to heave

Tags: concrete, garage, foundation, driveway

I mostly hear about this happening for roads on very hot days, but I'm wondering what about the heat causes the concrete to heave? Is there any concerns for foundations/garage floors/drive way heaving for the same reason? If so, what can I do to protect them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

heat causes it to expand. If there's no room to expand, it buckles. It's usually a bigger issue for blacktop, as it's darker and absorbs more heat. I doubt your house foundation or driveway has enough exposed mass for this to be of any concern, though...you typically need highway amounts of surface to cause the buckling

Comment: Just to add to this answer, the one thing you can do is put in expansion strips into an expanse of cement. Highways and sidewalks are often seen with them for just this purpose - a rubber strip between sections. I doubt you need it for a floor the size of a typical home garage, which will be shaded from direct sunlight anyway.